# Datatables plugin working fine on localhost but not on server (CPanel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been trying to get the DataTables plugin to work on my webserver, but it fails. On localhost, it works perfectly, but on the server, it shows all of the records without pagination and says "showing 0/0 of 0 entries", and when I attempt to use the search function, I get "No data is available in table". It seems like DataTables is not recognizing the data somehow.

I opened the console to check for errors, but I get none.

I'm using CPanel to handle everything.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datatables CDN -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

For the table data, I put data in myself for testing. Here is a sample:

```
<script>
let accountCreationData = [
            { AccountCreationEmail: 'Doomguy@doomguy.com', AccountCreationSendDate: '9/8/2021'},
            { AccountCreationEmail: 'Doomguy@doomguy.com', AccountCreationSendDate: '8/8/2021'},
            { AccountCreationEmail: 'Doomguy@doomguy.com', AccountCreationSendDate: '8/8/2021'},
............
```

And then I built the table like so:

```
dataHtml1 += `<tr class="notFirst"><td class = "AccountCreationClass"><div>${account.AccountCreationEmail}</div></td><td class = "AccountCreationClass"><div>${account.AccountCreationSendDate}</div></td><td><div class = "redCell"><b>&nbsp;Yes</b></div></td></tr>`;
```

And the script for the DataTables:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#AccountCreationInvitationTable').DataTable({
        'ordering': false,
        'lengthChange': false,
    }); 

    $('#ActiveAccountTableTableID').DataTable({
        'ordering': false,
        'lengthChange': false,
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Here is what it looks like on localhost:

[image: localhost is working]

Here is what it looks like on the webserver:

[image: not working on webserver]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies somewhere in the configuration of the webserver that I'm using, which is beyond my talents. Here is a link to a page where I found a solution that may work, if anyone else is facing this issue later.

Keep in mind that I did not solve the problem. This link is only a lead that I found to a possible solution.

I have decided to pursue other methods of pagination.

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2016

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: That's because I could not find the solution. I answered solely to give other people a lead, if they run into the same issue as I did. I found that link after hours of looking.